# adding an incremental counter to loop in a python parsing script

Tags: python, json

At the moment I'm using the following python script:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

with open('prettyPrint.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

locations = defaultdict(list)


for item in data['data']:
    location = item['relationships']['location']['data']['id']
    locations[location].append(item['id'])

pprint(locations)
```

to parse some dirty json data like so:

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs?skills=data%20science"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 121,
            "type": "job",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "Data Scientist",
                "date": "2014-01-22T15:25:00.000Z",
                "description": "Data scientists are in increasingly high demand amongst tech companies in London. Generally a combination of business acumen and technical skills are sought. Big data experience ..."
            },
            "relationships": {
                "location": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/location"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "location",
                        "id": 3
                    }
                },
                "country": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/country"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "country",
                        "id": 1
                    }
                },
```

At this point the output is in this way:

```
         85: [36026,
              36028,
              36032,
              36027,
              217897,
              286398,
              315064,
              320879,
              322303,
              322608,
              322611,
              323199,
              325659,
              327652],
         88: [13690,
              13693,
              13689,
              13692,
              13691,
              16454,
              16453,
              28002,
              28003,
              28004,
              28001,
              114667,
              233319,
              233329,
              263814,
              271490,
              271571,
              271569,
              271570,
              291274,
              291275,
              300376,
              300373,
              301293,
              301295,
              304286,
              304285,
              320425,
              320426,
              320424,
              320431,
              320430,
              321284,
              321281,
              321283,
              321282,
              321280,
              324345,
              327926,
              347985,
              358537,
              358549,
              357807,
              364541,
              358431,
              334990,
              359241],
```

But I'd like to change it so that the output looks like this:

```
         ...
         87: 02
         88: 73
         89: 15
         90: 104
         ...
```

I know I need to put some kind of `i=0`, `i++` into that loop somewhere- but I can't figure it out- how to do that?

Comment: How does the intended output relate to the original data?

Comment: Usually if you're thinking about using C-style incremeters like `i++`, there almost always a better way in Python, e.g. `enumerate`, `itertools.count`, `collections.Counter`.  These usually do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the count of the items in the dict, not the actual items to be part of the `locations` dict. Use `int` with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
locations = defaultdict(int)
# makes default value of each key as `0`
```

and make your `for` loop as:

```
for item in data['data']:
    location = item['relationships']['location']['data']['id']
    locations[location] += 1   # increase the count by `1`
```

OR, it is even better to use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) along with *generator expression*, as mentioned by @TigerhawkT3:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(item['relationships']['location']['data'‌​]['id'] for item in data['data'])
```

Comment: Or a `collections.Counter`, which was specifically made for counting.

Comment: `collections.Counter(item['relationships']['location']['data']['id'] for item in data['data'])`?